# Inserting a workspace on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, workspaces

In Ubuntu 18.04 when a workspace has no more windows it is automatically removed and the workspaces which were over and under the removed workspace become adjacent.

Is there any way to perform the reverse of that?

I have two adjacent workspaces which both have multiple windows, and I would like to move a window from one of these workspaces to a new workspace between the two existing workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this with the mouse. On the overview screen you can move windows between workspaces by dragging them to the right where the workspaces are shown. If you drag a window between two workspaces, it will open up a new one there.

Unfortunately, I don't know whether this can be done with a hotkey as well (it would be great).